# Did Fiske Cahill try to stop the Holts from blowing up the Franklin Institute?

Tags: the-39-clues

In [The Maze of Bones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Maze_of_Bones), Fiske (known as the Man in Black) is at the Franklin Institute in Boston when the Holts blow it up. His job is supposedly to watch over Amy and Dan and know everything about the other teams.

**Did he know that the Holts were going to blow up the museum? Did he try to stop them?**